# Предлог "из-под" в значении вместилища чего-либо

Tags: предлоги

Со всяким ли вместилищем корректен предлог "из-под"? Или только со стеклотарой и напитками?

Например: упаковка из-под чая, посуда из-под сахара и т. д.

Comment: ИЗ-ПОД; ИЗ-ПОДО, предлог. <...> 4. Указывает на прежнее назначение предмета, служившего вместилищем чего-л. _Бутылка из-под молока. Коробка из-под конфет. Банка из-под сметаны. Ящик из-под пива._  См. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4&all=x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**из-под**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/19540/%D0%B8%D0%B7) и **из-подо**, *предлог с род. п.* (МАС)
4. Употребляется при определении предмета посредством указания на его прежнее назначение служить вместилищем чего-либо. *Бутылка из-под молока.

**В коробке из-под ваксы** лежало много разнообразных пуговиц* (Горький).
*[Грузовики] почти доверху были завалены порожними **мешками из-под муки*** (Казакевич).

Вместилище — это понятие широкое. Сосуд, контейнер, емкость, тара, упаковка — выбирайте, лишь бы в нем прежде что-то лежало, стояло или плескалось.

Ящик из-под яблок, горшок из-под меда, цистерна или канистра из-под бензина, ведерко из-под майонеза, корзина из-под цветов,  бочка из-под коньяка, вазочка из-под печенья.

*А где-то там, под корнями, до сих пор лежит темная двухведерная **амфора из-под пшеницы**, полная золотых и серебряных монет...* (Д. Емец)

*Однажды я вспомнил кэрролловскую фразу о том, что **банки из-под варенья** никогда не бывают пустыми* (С. Вахитов).

*Основной объект его интереса – довоенные и послевоенные советские **упаковки из-под чая**, причем он собрал уже по-настоящему солидную коллекцию, даже сделал каталог* (К. Метелица).